# GLFW Fails to initialise. Raspberry Pi, EGL

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi2, glfw, egl

I'm compiling glfw3 (3.2.1) on the raspberry pi with no xserver with the option:

```
option(GLFW_USE_EGL "Use EGL for context creation" ON )
```

as per GLFW docs under **[EGL Specific CMake options](http://bit.ly/21khmqb)**.

The steps I've taken are:

```
wget https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/download/3.1.2/glfw-3.1.2.zip
unzip glfw-3.1.2.zip
cd glfw-3.1.2
nano CMakeLists.txt
```

then added the following to CMakeLists.txt:

```
option(GLFW_USE_EGL "Use EGL for context creation" ON )
```

Then install:

```
sudo cmake .
sudo make clean install
```

When I run the examples I get the error:

```
Failed to initialize GLFW
```

When I run my app I get:

```
X11: Failed to open display :0.0
```

It looks like GLFW is not using EGL and trying to get a window from X11...

Am I using the GLFW_USE_EGL incorrectly?